# React Footer overlapping component

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, footer, styling

I have been trying to create a footer that sticks to the bottom without overlapping any component but I am having some difficulties.

I have used the following code in my index:

```
.footer{
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #3D938B;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I have also added the footer just like any other component to the page...

```
<Router>
  <NavBar></NavBar>
  <div className={classes.topMargin}>
    <Route exact path="/contact-us" element={<ContactUs/>}/>
  </div>
  <Footer></Footer>
</Router>
```

My contact-us page has the following CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .form-container {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .button-submit {
        background-color: white;
        width:7rem;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 2px solid #3D938B;
        color: #3D938B;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-bottom:20px;

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As it is there's not enough information to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to make footer stick to bottom without overlap over other elements.

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #3D938B;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I don't have a body on my footer.

Would the css above be applied to the footer component?